# Add to Cart Function Location

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I´m totally new to Woocommerce and Wordpress in general. 
I understand the principle of Hooks and Action, but I don´t know where they are defined.

My plan is to change the action that happens when Add to Cart is pressed, but I don´t know where the code for that is located and can´t find it.

I don´t know if it matters but I´m using the Theme Flatsome.

Comment: the premise of changing the action that happens when "Add to Cart" is clicked is probably flawed.  What are you trying to accomplish? IF you are already familiar with filters / actions, then get yourself a good IDE (such as [PHPStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/)) and do a cross-file search in the plugin for `apply_filters` or `do_action`.

Comment: I want to have a Popup appear. With this popup I´m validating some stuff and I need the customer to agree. If he does it the product will be add to the cart regularly. If not ofc it won´t be added.

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/98740/lightbox-popup-on-woocommerce-add-to-cart-action

Comment: Yes but where are those located ? And how can I change the actions of the hooks.

Comment: If you want a popup then that's pure frontend and you shouldn't even need to know the serverside hooks/actions.

Comment: **Read my first comment.  I indicated how to find the hooks / filters that you want**.

Comment: I´m downloading all my files right now. Takes some time, then I´ll try it how you explained it.

Answer (score 0):

Hook and Action allow to edit server-side behavior.

It seems that you want to edit client-side. You have to edit theme, using javascript or bootstrap to launch a modal (or popup), after you have to using woocommerce override to edit and alter cart behavior.

Take a look here: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/

Comment: Welcome to SO, and thanks for trying to help.  This answer doesn't really help, and should be a comment.  Further, link-only answers are no good because **when the link breaks**, the answer has no value to future visitors.